# Use iOS-Charts How to set the label position of the X axis and the position of the bar, line

Tags: ios-charts

**I want need to be done like this,**

[image]

**but I made this after I do not know how to do it.** 
[image]

**I want understand the attributes of the IOS chart, the first picture on both sides of the column does not show completely, I would like to two columns and X axis of the label indentation, how to set up?**

**Can who help me?
Thank you!**

Comment: What you need here be clear ? by adding image its not enough to get whats issue you are facing Please add some more detail to help your self.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to see the whole width of the yellow bar for April. This should force the bar to be shown:

```
 chartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
 chartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 3.0, maxXRange: 3.0)
```

If you change the 0.0 to a bigger number it should move the yellow bar more to the right.

You can also try changing the number 3.0 to a bigger number and see what effect it gives you.