# ios-charts combined chart: bars going past right axis of chart

Tags: ios, charts, bar-chart, linechart, ios-charts

I'm trying to make something similar to this

[image: jom8o]

Im going to have 4 BarChartDataSets grouped, and 2 LineChartDataSets, each data set has 7 data points, the user can add or remove these datasets at will

The bars seem to be grouping fine, and the line chart shows all 7 points

but as I add more BarChartDataSets to the chart, the bars go off the right side of the chart, the line chart stays the same, here is an image sequence of me starting with a single LineChartDataSet, then adding BarChartDataSets one by one, some of the bars have a value of 0, so its hard to see the group, look for the 0 label at the bottom

[image][image][image][image][image]

How can i stop the bars from going off the right of the chart?

Here is the code:

```
//get data and values from DataMOs in the activeFeeds
            var lineChartDataSets = [LineChartDataSet]()
            var barChartDataSets = [BarChartDataSet]()
            for (key, dayValuesArray) in valuesByFeed {
                var barChartDataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
                var lineChartDataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()
                var lineChartDataSet: LineChartDataSet!
                var barChartDataSet: BarChartDataSet!
                var dataEntry: ChartDataEntry

                for (index, value) in (dayValuesArray?.enumerated())! {
                    //create line chart for Demand and Prod feeds
                    //create bar chart for every other feed
                    if key == "Demand" || key == "Prod"{
                        dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(self.activeFeeds.count * index), y: Double(value)!)
                        lineChartDataEntries.append(dataEntry)
                    } else {
                        dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(self.activeFeeds.count * index), y: Double(value)!)
                        barChartDataEntries.append(dataEntry as! BarChartDataEntry)
                    }
                }

                //create line chart data set for Demand and Prod feeds
                //create bar chart data set for every other feed
                if key == "Demand" || key == "Prod"{
                    lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartDataEntries, label: key)
                    lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
                } else {
                    barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: barChartDataEntries, label: key)
                }

                switch key {
                case "Solar":
                    barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
                    barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
                    break
                case "Wind":
                    barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
                    barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
                    break
                case "Battery":
                    barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
                    barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
                    break
                case "Gen":
                    barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
                    barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
                    break
                case "Demand":
                    lineChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
                    lineChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
                    lineChartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
                    lineChartDataSet.fillColor = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
                    break
                case "Prod":
                    lineChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.magenta.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
                    lineChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
                    lineChartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
                    lineChartDataSet.fillColor = UIColor.magenta.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }

                //append to correct data set array
                if key == "Demand" || key == "Prod"{
                    lineChartDataSets.append(lineChartDataSet)
                } else {
                    barChartDataSets.append(barChartDataSet)
                }
            }

            //set chart data
            let chartData = CombinedChartData()
            chartData.barData = BarChartData(dataSets: barChartDataSets)
            chartData.lineData = LineChartData(dataSets: lineChartDataSets)
            let activeFeedsCount = self.activeFeeds.count
            if activeFeedsCount > 0 {
                self.combinedChartView.data = chartData
                if chartData.barData.dataSetCount > 1 {
                    self.combinedChartView.barData?.groupBars(fromX: 0, groupSpace: 1.0, barSpace: 0.5)
                    self.combinedChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            } else {
                self.combinedChartView.data = CombinedChartData()
                self.combinedChartView.noDataText = "No Feeds To Show"
            }
```

Comment: using setVisibleXRange could solve the problem, see this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44852890/5881884 if it doesn't solve it, can you share some code so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: didn't seem to work, I added the code im working with, its basically data points for the last 7 days, there will be 7 groups of 4 bars, and 2 line charts with 7 data points each

Comment: Then I suggest changing granularity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856224/5881884

Comment: as you can see from the code above, i am already trying to use that, changing its value does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the problem with the 0 label, but it is possible to use combinedChart.xAxis.axisMaximum to make sure you can see all the bars to the right.

```
 let activeFeeds = 6
 func dataSet() {

    combinedChart.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    combinedChart.scaleXEnabled = false
    combinedChart.scaleYEnabled = false

    combinedChart.dragEnabled = true
    //combinedChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
    combinedChart.xAxis.axisMaximum = 100.0

    //get data and values from DataMOs in the activeFeeds
    var lineChartDataSets = [LineChartDataSet]()
    var barChartDataSets = [BarChartDataSet]()
    combinedChart.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 0.0, maxXRange: 26.0)

    let arr1 = [17000,16500,16800,16700,17900,17100,18000]
    let arr2 = [17000,17500,16900,16800,17200,17105,17000]

    let valuesByFeed = ["Solar":arr1, "Wind": arr2, "Battery": arr1, "Gen":arr1, "Demand":arr1, "Prod":arr1]

    for (key, dayValuesArray) in valuesByFeed {
        var barChartDataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
        var lineChartDataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()
        var lineChartDataSet: LineChartDataSet!
        var barChartDataSet: BarChartDataSet!
        var dataEntry: ChartDataEntry

        for (index, value) in (dayValuesArray.enumerated()) {
            //create line chart for Demand and Prod feeds
            //create bar chart for every other feed
            if key == "Demand" || key == "Prod"{
                dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(self.activeFeeds * index), y: Double(value))
                lineChartDataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            } else {
                dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(self.activeFeeds * index), y: Double(value))
                barChartDataEntries.append(dataEntry as! BarChartDataEntry)
            }
        }


        //create line chart data set for Demand and Prod feeds
        //create bar chart data set for every other feed
        if key == "Demand" || key == "Prod"{
            lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartDataEntries, label: key)
            lineChartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        } else {
            barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: barChartDataEntries, label: key)
        }

        switch key {
        case "Solar":
            print("case solar")
            barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            break
        case "Wind":
            print("case wind")
            barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            break
        case "Battery":
            print("case battery")
            barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            break
        case "Gen":
            print("case gen")

            barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            break
        case "Gen2":
            print("case gen")

            barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            break
        case "Gen3":
            print("case gen")

            barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            break
        case "Gen4":
            print("case gen")

            barChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            barChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            break


        case "Demand":
            print("case demand")

            lineChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            lineChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            lineChartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
            lineChartDataSet.fillColor = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            break
        case "Prod":
            print("case prod")

            lineChartDataSet.setColors(UIColor.magenta.withAlphaComponent(1.0))
            lineChartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            lineChartDataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
            lineChartDataSet.fillColor = UIColor.magenta.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        //append to correct data set array
        if key == "Demand" || key == "Prod"{
            lineChartDataSets.append(lineChartDataSet)
        } else {
            barChartDataSets.append(barChartDataSet)
        }
    }

    //set chart data
    let chartData = CombinedChartData()
    print("bar count: \(barChartDataSets.count)")
    print("line count: \(lineChartDataSets.count)")
    chartData.barData = BarChartData(dataSets: barChartDataSets)
    chartData.lineData = LineChartData(dataSets: lineChartDataSets)
    let activeFeedsCount = self.activeFeeds
    if activeFeedsCount > 0 {
        self.combinedChart.data = chartData
        if chartData.barData.dataSetCount > 1 {
            self.combinedChart.barData?.groupBars(fromX: 0, groupSpace: 1.0, barSpace: 0.5)
            self.combinedChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    } else {
        self.combinedChart.data = CombinedChartData()
        self.combinedChart.noDataText = "No Feeds To Show"
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: i used this with a combination of fitToScreen() thanks